# Error when closing a explorer window through a userform

Tags: vba, excel

I have a minor issue for one of the features on my userform.  If a user clicks the "Browse" button but doesn't click the "Open" button after selecting a file, and instead either closes the window or selects "Cancel", a Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument  is displayed.

Ideally if the user closes the window or selects "Cancel" I would like the user to be returned to the form.  I know I'm missing some code but don't know what or where it should go.  Below is the code I have;

```
Private Sub CommandButtonPicture_File_Browse_Click()

    Dim FindFile As Office.FileDialog
    Dim FoundFile As Variant

    Set FindFile = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)

    With FindFile

        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "Jpegs", "*.jpg;*.jpeg*"
        .Filters.Add "Png", "*.png*"
        .Filters.Add "Gif", "*.gif*"
        .Filters.Add "Bitmaps", "*.bmp*"
        .Filters.Add "PDF", "*.pdf*"
        .Filters.Add "All Files", "*.*"

        .AllowMultiSelect = False


        If .Show = True Then
         TextBoxPicture_File_Link.Value = .SelectedItems(1)
        End If
        Me.TextBoxPicture_File_Link = .SelectedItems(1)

    End With

End Sub
```

Please note, the code currently works it adds the file link to text box as intended, it's just the issue discussed above that's a problem.

Comment: Any line referencing `SelectedItems` needs to be inside the `If` block.  But that line outside the block seems to be a duplicate...

Comment: Thank you that solved the issue. (Odd thing, though that duplicate line is needed for the code to work.)

Comment: probably because the line inside the `If` block does not work